How long do I need to wait between ESTA applications?
I'm a UK citizen. I want to travel to the USA for a holiday and to see some friends.
I've used an ESTA a few times in the past and it was fairly straightforward. However this time I'd like to spend longer in the USA with a break eg:
2 months in the USA.
2 months in Latin America.
2 months in the USA again.
I can't do this with a single ESTA, so how long do I need to wait between ESTA applications? The official wording is unclear so even some anecdotal advice would be helpful.

"I can't do this with a single ESTA" - what leads you to believe that?

An ESTA is valid for 2 years. You don't need to apply for a new one unless the previous one has expired (before the date of arrival in the US, it does not even need to remain valid for the whole duration of your stay) or there have been significant changes (e.g. you have a new passport or you changed name)

If you mean (and I think you do) "how long must I wait between trips using the Visa Waiver Program" then please edit. ESTA is just permission to fly while using the Visa Waiver Program. Google "Visa Waiver Program".

@AakashM: One reasonable case why you can't do it on a single ESTA is when your old ESTA between the two trips, ie. in the above case while in Latin America.

Quoting the official ESTA website FAQ:

When should I submit an application through ESTA?
Applications may be submitted at any time prior to travel to the United States. The Department of Homeland Security recommends that travel authorization applications be submitted at least 72 hours prior to travel. Unless revoked, travel authorizations are valid for two years from the date of authorization, or until your passport expires, whichever comes first.

(emphasis mine).
So you can do both trips with a single ESTA. You could probably even use an existing ESTA if it's still valid.
Note that it only needs to be valid at the time you enter the US, it does not even need to be valid for the whole duration of your trip. In you case, it needs to be valid on each of the two arrivals into the US.
Note however that an ESTA does not guarantee entry into the US, you still need to meet all entry requirements. While 2 months or even 2 x 2 months in a year with 2 months outside the US in between is definitely not an issue per se, they may ask questions about your intended activities in the US, what you do, how you can support yourself for 4 months in a year without working, etc.

I assumed with an ESTA that you couldn't just leave the USA and come back. Are there any guidelines on how long (if any) period you need to stay out the country for? I couldn't see this exactly on the FAQ page.

@Evanss An ESTA is valid for 2 years, you can make as many trips as you want to the US while it's valid (though again, it does not guarantee entry, just that you can travel there). Your presence in the US is not governed by ESTA but by the VWP (Visa Waiver Program). On the VWP, you can stay up to 90 days per stay. You should not use repeated or successive visits to live in the US. The rule of thumb is to stay as long outside as you stayed in. Note that short visits to Canada, Mexico and some of the neighbouring islands are counted, so they do not "reset" your time in the US. You can't work.

Related questions What is the US Visa Waiver Programme and what is an ESTA, Any documents to show when entering US with ESTA and Can I enter the US twice within 90 days

@Evanss You can’t see any guidelines on how long (if any) period you need to stay out the country for because the US does not have a fixed calculation of ‘allowed stay’ rule such as the Schengen 90/180 day rule. Similar to the UK, what typically matters is eg the frequency/length/purpose of visits.

@Evanss: If you've used multiple ESTA's in the past, the US has a record of you spanning many years. Don't worry too much; your history is in your favour. You've come to the US, stayed for a while, and then left again. That makes it believable you'll do so again. 4 months in one year might be a lot for a first-time visitor, but you're not.
